# haskell generics documentation incorrect?

Tags: haskell

I've been going through the [GHC Generics documentation here](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics) and it seems the example code is incorrect. The part I have trouble with is this:

```
type RepUserTree a =
  -- A UserTree is either a Leaf, which has no arguments
      U1
  -- ... or it is a Node, which has three arguments that we put in a product
  :+: a :*: UserTree a :*: UserTree a
```

given that the the `(:*:)` type operator is defined as `data (:*:) f g p = f p :*: g p`, as expected, the above bit of code gives the kind error:

```
 Blockquotetest.hs:26:13: error:
    • Expecting one fewer argument to ‘UserTree a’
      Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘UserTree a’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘:*:’, namely ‘UserTree a’
      In the second argument of ‘:*:’, namely ‘UserTree a :*: UserTree a’
      In the second argument of ‘:+:’, namely
        ‘a :*: (UserTree a :*: UserTree a)’
```

Is the documentation incorrect? Am I missing an extension that makes the above work? I'm not really sure how to go about changing the above to compile.

Comment: I think that example is meant to be informal, an not real Haskell code. That's not made explicit in the example text, which makes it quite confusing. Anyway, I'd say you are correct above. A real working definition is shown below the informal example, and is called `RealRepUserTree` ("real" points out that the first one was a dummy) but it's much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a dummy example to give you an idea of what it is doing because the details are a bit more complex. But it might be worth understanding why it doesn't compile because it is good to understand what is going wrong in these situations if you want to do any sort of type level programming in Haskell.

If you look at the type parameters of `(:+:)` and `(:*:)`, you can see that they each take three types, `f g p`. They are both kind `* -> * -> * -> *`.

```
data (:+:) f g p = L1 (f p) | R1 (g p)
data (:*:) f g p = f p :*: g p
```

and `p` is given to `f` and `g`, so we know that `f` and `g` must be at least kind `* -> *`. The `UserTree` type's kind is `* -> *`.

```
data UserTree a = Node a (UserTree a) (UserTree a) | Leaf
```

but in the declaration we have `UserTree a`, which is of kind `*` whereas what (:*:) is expecting two things of at least kind `* -> *`.

```
type RepUserTree a = U1 :+: a :*: UserTree a :*: UserTree a
```

If you remove the `a` you get it to compile.

```
type RepUserTree a = U1 :+: a :*: UserTree :*: UserTree
```

Now look at `U1`, `K1` and `M1` they all end in the `p` parameter. Notice that in the `RealRepUserTree` example, `U1`, `K1` and `M1` all take one type less they than can. These meets the requirements of both `(:+:)` and `(:*:)`.